# subset of all real valued functions of a real variable is subring but not an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

$STATEMENT:$

Let $R$ be the ring of all real-valued functions of a real variable.
The subset $S$ of all differentiable functions is a subring of R but not an ideal of R.

$Question:$

I think subset $S$ is clearly subring of $R$. ($f$,$g$ $\in$ $S$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ - $g$ $\in$ $S$, $fg$ $\in$ $S$)

But I cannot imagine $S$ is not an ideal of $R$. 
Can you give some example?

Thanks for all answer.

Comment: Do you think $f$ differentiable implies $fg$ differentiable for all $g$? For example, what if $f\equiv 1$ and $g$ isn’t differentiable?

Comment: Is it right $f,g$ differentiable implies $fg$ differentiable? If just $f$ differentiable, I think you are right.

Comment: Yes, from the basic definition of the derivative as a limit of a difference quotient (show this!).

Comment: If $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$ and $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} = g'(x)$, then
$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)+g(x+h)f(x)-g(x+h)f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(x+h)[f(x+h)-f(x)]}{h} + \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)[g(x+h)-g(x)]}{h} = g(x)f'(x) + g'(x)f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an ideal because it's not true that $rs \in S$ for every $r \in R$ and $s \in S$. In other words, if $s$ is a differentiable function, and $r$ is any general real-valued function, then $rs$ is not always differentiable. In general, it may not even be continuous!

For example, observe that $s = e^{x}$ is differentiable. Hence $s \in S$. However, let 
$$
r = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
-1 & \text{if } x \not\in \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $r \in R$ because it is a real-valued function. But note that 
$$
rs = 
\begin{cases}
e^x & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
-e^x & \text{if } x \not\in \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$
is not differentiable. In fact it's not even continuous. So $rs \not\in S$. Hence it is not true that $rs \in S$ for every $r \in R$, $s \in S$, so we see that $S$ is not an ideal of $R$.

However, it's clearly a subring since it's nonempty and the product and difference of differentiable functions is differentiable.

Comment: thanks for answer.